# Why does my chart not appears correctly?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have created a function to return a datatable from a stored procedure. Then I created another function to fill chart from datatable but my chart does not appear as full. Only Series names appears (see picture). [image: mychart]

I have two columns in my datatable `location_name` and `recount`

My function

```
public void FillChartReciversByLocations()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            BL.recivers rec= new BL.recivers();
            dt = rec.ReciversByLocations();
            chart1.DataSource = dt;
            chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string SeriesName = dt.Rows[i]["location_name"].ToString();
                chart1.Series.Add(SeriesName);
                chart1.Series[SeriesName].XValueMember ="location_name";
                chart1.Series[SeriesName].YValueMembers = "reccount";
            }
            chart1.DataBind();

        }
```

Comment: What are the axis settings? Why are they not displaying?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all i got the solution after trying many times  the true code is

```
 public void FillChartReciversByLocations()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            BL.recivers rec= new BL.recivers();
            dt = rec.ReciversByLocations();
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            chart1.DataSource = dt;
            string SeriesName = dt.Rows[0]["location_name"].ToString();
            chart1.Series.Add(SeriesName);
            chart1.Series[SeriesName].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;
            chart1.Series[SeriesName].XValueMember = "location_name";
           chart1.Series[SeriesName].YValueMembers = "reccount";


        }
```